# How to do turn off vibration in Ionic 2 app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins, android-vibration

I have tried using plugin `@ionic-native/vibration` and tried three ways

```
   navigator.vibrate(0);
   (<any>window).vibration.vibrate(0);
```

And

```
   import { Vibration } from '@ionic-native/vibration';
     constructor(private vibration: Vibration){
       this.vibration.vibrate(0);
   }
```

also added to app module

but its not working, Is there any other way to do setting vibration to 0 or turn off vibrations.

Comment: This will presumably only turn off vibrations for your app, not system-wide. Is that perhaps the confusion?

Comment: The Vibration plugin is only used to vibrate the device. When does the vibrating appear ? You mean when your receive a push notification or so ?

Comment: Hello, i want to set vibration to 0 (off) while incoming call or any vibration event of mobile phone,....

Comment: @rajnish You can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there's currently no way to completely turn off vibrations that would be sent by some other component than your App.

However, there might be a trick to disable some vibrations given certain circumstances, using `vibrate(0)` as you did. [The documentation on `vibrate`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/vibration/#vibrate) reads

> [...] Pass 0 to stop any vibration immediately.

So you can't completely shut down incoming vibrations, but you can cancel any current vibration. So if for example you want to cancel the vibration of a notification you send, you can call `vibrate(0)` just as it arrives.

It **is** a poor workaround as you'll probably need to call it multiple times to cancel the vibration (to be sure you call this *after* the vibration started), but I think it's the only solution approaching what you're trying to achieve using only Ionic.

Or you could also periodically and very often call `vibrate(0)` to cancel any incoming vibration but it would **not recommand** this because to be effective the delay would have to be super short, which is probably a bad idea for performance reasons. I'm merely saying this as an emergency solution.